# How to retrieve file in v-file-input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<v-file-input
    accept="image/*"
    label="File input"
    v-model="chosenFile"
></v-file-input>
```

Im using vue js, How can get back the files content?

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var img = new Image();
reader.readAsDataURL(this.chosenFile)
```

When I use FileReader, it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/eveningforgery/pen/KKzWrwq

You need to use the reader's result which is the blob of the image in order to display it or save it somewhere

```html
<img v-if="data" :src="data" alt="">
```

```js
importImage() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
      
  // Use the javascript reader object to load the contents
  // of the file in the v-model prop
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.chosenFile)
  reader.onload = () => {
    this.data = reader.result;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i pass the file object to php?

Comment: Depending on your use case you probably want to save it in the cloud first, like aws or any other cdn really, then save the file's url in your database through an api you'd build in your backend. Without more details I can't really know what would be best, you should make another question.

Comment: Great Thanks Bro~